# How can I make my computer sound like computers on TV?

Tags: audio, themes

When you're watching *CSI*, *Law & Order*, or any movie where they show how hi-tech the characters are when they use a computer, the computer always beeps and blips along... when stuff scrolls on the screen it goes deet-deet-deet-deet-deet... when they zoom in on something it goes blip-blip-blip etc etc. Most of the sounds are very short & high pitched.

How can I make my Windows sound like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I took it a step further and just developed my own sound theme. It's a bunch of WAV files and a reg file... anyone who might delight in their PC sounding "super-high-tech" may help themselves... (for Windows XP/Vista/7)

http://www.shoey.com/apps/csi/CSI.zip

**CSI - "Computer Sounds Integration"**

I thought it would be fun to create a sound theme that made my machine sound like something from the set of CSI. With some inspiration from Nullsoft Beep and http://www.dewa.com/sound (admittedly, some of the sounds are modified versions of sounds available on dewa.com) I cranked up my audio editor and began synthesizing some sounds.

The result was a sound theme for Windows XP/Vista/7 that provides Hollywood-style sound effects for your computer.

Installation:

1. Download the CSI.zip file
2. Extract the CSI folder as a subfolder in your C:\Windows\Media folder.
3. Double click the "CSI Sound Scheme.reg" registry file and import the CSI registry settings
4. Open Control Panel and go to the Sound applet
5. Choose CSI as your sound scheme
6. Enjoy! (I'm a FF user, but the sounds are better with IE)

If your Windows folder is not C:\Windows, open the reg file in a text editor and do a global replace of "C:\\Windows" with the appropriate path to your Windows folder. Be sure to include the double backslashes.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure out how to make my own sound schemes. Also, I like the CSI theme, but I have a feeling it will be driving me crazy in a couple of days or so.

Comment: Beware that Git IDEs can drive you crazy with the Windows, Open Program sound.

Answer (score 7):

There's [Nullsoft's "Beep"](http://www.1014.org/code/nullsoft/nbeep/):

> Nullsoft Beep is an application that
>   makes your computer sound like
>   computers sound in the movies. It
>   requires Windows 95 or later with
>   DirectX 3 or later. features
>
> - Excitement-Generation Technology[tm].
> - Hyper-Auto-Blips[tm] on screen updates and keyboard input.
> - Variable low hum dependent on system CPU load.
> - System tray icon.
> - Install and uninstall support.
> - Source code included!

Comment: +1 Holy Cow!!! Excitement Generation Technology is right ... makes your computer sound like a certain well-known little robot in the movies is more like it :P

Comment: HAHAHA! +111111

Comment: LMAO - it really gets noisy after a while. It's a hoot. Nice one.